# Why are all my Firefox downloads opened by VLC media player?

Tags: firefox, vlc

It has been more than one week, and Firefox has started opening any downloaded file with VLC media player, even if I change the source of opening the file. In the next download, it will open again with VLC media player. What should I do?

Comment: vlc may be set as your default video player.

Comment: Yes it is  set as my default video player but it is opening any file even if it is a text or a picture

Comment: In the Firefox preferences, there's a section called "Applications". Which types are VLC associated with in that list?

Comment: I checked, vlc is only opening multimedia files in the mentioned section. For the others, there is a comment saying 'Always ask' but in the reality it takes vlc as the default opener and doesn't give any other suggestions

Comment: Does it happen if you open Firefox with a different profile? Run `firefox -P`, create a new profile and try with it.

Comment: Yes, I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and I resolved it like this:

--> Open the file `.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` with a text editor (`gedit` for example).

--> If you have this line:

```
    application/octet-stream=vlc.desktop;

erase `vlc.desktop`
```

--> Save & restart computer

note: the "mimeapps.list" is now stored in /home/userprofil/.config/mimeapps.list in Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I upvoted the answer but I would like to report that it is not necessary to restart the computer. As soon as it is saved, we can choose at the next download the application we want to use to open the file. After the choice was made, the next time, it will not be asked anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Lubuntu 18.04:

right-click on the lx panel, choose *Panel Settings*

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HY90X.png)

go to the *Advanced*  tab

choose Filemanager PCManFM from *File Manager* drop down menu.

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2dIm.png)